# How to know if matrices $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ grow towards infinity when exponentiated to $M^{n \rightarrow \infty}$

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

I'm looking for a way to define quadratic matrices $M\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ such that when I raise them to the power of $n$ they won't have any entry growing towards infinity. (They also shouldn't converge to zero if possible, but that's not so important.)

Is there some criterion assuring this property (but still not restricting the possible values too much)?

(I know, this is school math, but I forgot and I couldn't find the solution anywhere on the internet.)

(So far I looked at the standard recursive formula for each entry of $M^n$: $$M^n_{ik}=\sum_{j=1}^m M_{ij} \cdot M^{n-1}_{jk}$$
yielding a nested chain of sums and multiplications, but I was not able to resolve it in any effective way.)

Comment: If your eigenvalues are small ($|\lambda|\leq 1$), then this should work.  Take a look at powers of the Jordan form.

Comment: You can use stochastic matrices (sum of each row is $1$).

Comment: to complete slightly Michael's answer, if one eigenvalue has modulus $>1$ the iterates will diverge, if all the eigenvalues are $<1$ the iterates will go to zero, and if one eigenvalue has modulus $=1$ it will not go to zero but may or may not diverge (it will diverge if the associated Jordan block has size $>1$)

Comment: If all eigenvalues of $M$ are strictly less than $1$ in modulus, then no entry of $M^n$ will blow up. If all eigenvalues of modulus $1$ are nondefective then the same is true. If an eigenvalue of modulus exactly $1$ is defective then $M^n$ will indeed blow up, as $M=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ shows through the fact $M^n=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. This all falls out of the Jordan form.

Comment: You could diagonalize and take the power of the diagonal matrix (if diagonalization is possible. Something like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597602/finding-a-2x2-matrix-raised-to-the-power-of-1000 )

Comment: Ok, great, some of this should work for my problem. Sticking to diagobalizable matrices is more restricktive, though, than the Eigenvalue approach - isn't it? (Thanks for the answers, I can't vote you up due to reputation.)

Comment: @Fnacool Just thinking - stochastic matrices might be the easiest solution. Thanks a lot!