# How fast does a matrix expression go to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, markov-chains, matrix-equations

> With $0<a,b,c<1$,
>   \begin{align}
> \begin{bmatrix} 
> X_n \\
> Y_n 
> \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 
> a^2 & (1-b)^2 \\
> (1-a)^2 & b^2 
> \end{bmatrix}^n \begin{bmatrix} 
> c^2 \\
> (1-c)^2 
> \end{bmatrix}
> \end{align}
>   How fast does $X_n+Y_n$ go to zero?

This is coming from a Markov chain problem which I solved up to here. We can see that $X_n\leq X_{n-1}$ and $Y_n\leq Y_{n-1}$. I am thinking of using the results of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597602/finding-a-2x2-matrix-raised-to-the-power-of-1000), but it does not seem easy. Any idea how to continue?

Comment: Your matrix isn't Markov. Are you sure that the two off-diagonal entries are correct? Should they read $1-a^2$ and $1-b^2$ instead?

Comment: @user1551 Yes, this is correct. It is calculating if two identical and independent Markov chains have the same state from the first up to the $n-th$ step. That's why we have $a^2$ and $(1-a)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your $2\times2$ matrix $A$. Since $a,b\in(0,1)$, all column sums of $A$ are strictly smaller than $1$, i.e. $\|A\|<1$ when the *induced* $1$-norm  is taken. Hence $\|A^n\|\le\|A\|^n$. Since all norms are equivalent, the *vector* $1$-norm of $A^n$, i.e. the maximum magnitude of all entries of $A^n$, is $O(\|A\|^n)$. Hence $|X_n+Y_n|=O(\|A\|^n)$ too.

Comment: Thanks. That's a beautiful and quick way of solving it. Can you elaborate more on the last step?

Comment: @Susan_Math123 Done. See my new edit.

Comment: Thanks. Is that a property that $||Az||\leq ||A|| ||z||$ when $z$ is a vector and $||\cdot||$ is the induced norm of order $1$?

Comment: @Susan_Math123 It's more part of the definition than a property. Given any norm $\|x\|$ on a vector space, its induced norm for a matrix is defined by $\|A\|=\max_{\|x\|\ne0}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$. When the $1$-norm $\|x\|=\sum_i|x_i|$ is taken, the induced matrix norm is called the induced $1$-norm and it is usually denoted by $\|A\|_1$. It is known that $\|A\|_1=\max_j\sum_i|a_{ij}|$. In your case, $A$ is entrywise positive, so $\|A\|_1$ is just the maximum column sum of $A$.

Comment: Very informative. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use eigenvectors and eigenvalues. These are pairs $v$ and $\lambda$, that fulfill $Av=v\lambda$ with $A$ being your matrix. 
Since you have a $2\times2$ matrix, I assume you will end up with a complex pair of values $\lambda_{1,2}$.

With this, you can show, that $\begin{bmatrix} X_n \\Y_n\end{bmatrix} \leq |\lambda|\begin{bmatrix}X_{n-1} \\ Y_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$
You will get geometric convergence to zero for both entries and therefore the sum.

Comment: Thanks. But, how can I show $|\lambda|<1$? The equation you gave holds for both $\lambda s$? How did you achieve it?

Comment: If the inequality you gave works for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, then I can show that $min(|\lambda_1|,|\lambda_2|)<1$ and I'll be done.

Comment: The eigenvalues should be a complex pair (assuming $a$ and $b$ are real) and have the same absolute value.
In general you need $\max(|\lambda_i|)< 1$ for convergence to zero

Comment: Not necessarily, I have a set of values for my matrix that leads to real eigenvalues.

Comment: I'm an idiot, thank you... In that case you need the larger one (assuming the general case) to be smaller than zero. A special case would be, that your starting vector is exactly the eigenvector of the smaller one.

Comment: Thanks. Can you let me know how did you find the inequality you provided? does it have a name? Is it on Wikipedia or anything that I can read?

Comment: It arises from something called "power iteration". A well known numerical method for computing eigenvalues of matrices. It is used there to show convergence to the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue.